# Recieve an error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a static class with one method:

```
namespace Creatives {
    export class CreativesService {
                static exportToExcel(): number {
                return 1;}
                                   }
                                }
```

and I import this method to another file, like this:

```
   import CS = Creatives;
   private onExportToExcelFile = (): void => {
            let str: number = CS.CreativesService.exportToExcel();
            alert(str);
        }
```

I recieve this error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CreativesService')

Why?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import `module-name` - "This is often a relative or absolute URL to the .js file containing the module."

Comment: `import CS = Creatives` doesn't look right. Please may you double-check how to use ESM imports?